# The right way to revers a sign for float numbers

Tags: php

I have a `debts` variable and it can have both positive and negative numbers. I need to display it for users with opposite sign.

I do it like this:

```
echo -$debts;
```

But if `$debts=0.00` i get `-0.00` instead of `0.00`.
The easiest solution i found for now is:

```
echo $debts == 0 ? $debts : -$debts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively

```
$negdebts = 0.00 - $debts
```

Then your zero maintains its sign